# How to change default database to all logins?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, authentication

I'm bit new to SQL and I'm trying to script out SQL post installation activities and I got bit stuck on altering logins. Corporate policy states that none login should have `master` database as default, thus my plan is to identify all logins that has `master` as default and change `master` to `tempdb`.

Single login can be altered using such query:

`ALTER LOGIN [sa] WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = tempdb`

Trying to achieve this on all logins (without knowing their amount nor names), I know I was naive, when hoping something like this would work (but had to try):

```
UPDATE master..syslogins
SET dbname = 'tempdb'
WHERE dbname = 'master'
```

Obviously output was error (which sounds logical):

`Ad hoc updates to system catalogs are not allowed.`

SQLs are in MIX authentication mode, so pretty much anything can be login - SQL login, Windows local or domain user or group (not sure if this can make any difference for solution). Solution should be pretty much version independent, but let's say starting SQL 2005 forward (...yes, still have some ancient version around...)

Can anyone please help me to find proper query to achieve this?

Thank you in advanced for any hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @LoginName  SYSNAME;
DECLARE @Sql        NVARCHAR(MAX);


DECLARE Cur CURSOR FOR
SELECT loginname 
FROM sys.syslogins
WHERE name NOT LIKE '%#%'  
   AND name  <> 'SA'
-- AND   --<-- here add more clauses to target the desired logins only    

OPEN Cur 
FETCH NEXT FROM  Cur INTO @LoginName

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
  SET @Sql = N'ALTER LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(@LoginName) 
           + N' WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = [tempdb];'

         -- PRINT @SQL  --<-- test before you actually execute it             
  EXEC (@SQL)

  FETCH NEXT FROM  Cur INTO @LoginName  
END 

CLOSE Cur;
DEALLOCATE Cur;
```

Comment: Perfect solution in the speed of light... thanks mate, this did the trick ;-)

Comment: Your welcome mate, just becareful you shouldn't be changing default database for default logins for Default SQL Server services.

Comment: When speaking of "default logins", that includes those prefixed and suffixed with ## I assume? Or any other I should rather avoid?